# Azure DevOps Pipeline task version

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to create a pipeline that will build the docker image and push it to ACR. Which version of the docker task should be used? does docker@2 supports backward compatibility with docker@1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which version of the docker task should be used? does docker@2
>   supports backward compatibility with docker@1

The higher version of one task is always **more recommended** cause newer version fixes some issues in old version and makes some improvement.

I'm not certainly about the `backward compatibility` you mean, but there's some difference 
 about task inputs between them. That means you **can't directly reuse** same script and task inputs from `docker@1` when using `docker@2` version. (Simply changing `Docker@1` to `Docker@2` without modifying task inputs may cause task to fail.)

E.g: In `docker@1`, `buildAndPush` command can receive `arguments`, but in `docker@2`, the `arguments` has been removed for `buildAndPush` command.

In addition: I found one open issue [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/7424) in which one member asks the vsts-document team to share more details about migrating `docker@1` to `docker@2`, you may comment and track the issue there to get notifications when there's change to the document itself.

Hope it helps :)